# Shadowed arguments in recursive function

Tags: go, recursion, scope

```
var f func(a *x, b int)
f = func(a *x, b int) {
    // a and b are changed here.
    if ... {
        return
    }
    for ... {
        c := new(x)
        *c = *a
        f(c, b)          
    }
}
```

The code illustrates the structure of my program.

I expected that after the return-statement is reached, the arguments are reset to the state prior to the recursive function call and the loop continues with the next iteration.

To my surprise, the debugger labels the expected values as shadowed and the program continues with the manipulated ones, set  by the recursive call.

How can I achieve the expected behavior?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no variable shadowing in the provided code. Please do not elide that part of the code that you need help with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If type `x` contains any pointer types, those must also be copied if you are updating them in the recursive call. For example, if `x` looked like this:

```
type x struct {
   d *y
}
```

You would need to update both x and y.

```
c := new(x)
*c = *a
d := new(y)
*c.d := *d
```

A better strategy might be to eliminate all pointers in the problem. If `a` were of type `x` and `d` were of type `y`, then `f(a, b)` would copy both values on invocation.